# How to configure persistent storage for jboss datagrid openshift image?

Tags: jboss, openshift, openshift-origin, infinispan-8

I have tried with templates provided at:
 https://github.com/jboss-openshift/application-templates/blob/master/datagrid/datagrid71-mysql-persistent.json.

However, my entries are deleted after pod restarts.
 The log is as follows:

```
 ISPN000149: Fetch persistent state and purge on startup are both disabled, cache may contain stale entries on startup
```